# vb.net arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow error

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to turn every value of an eight digit string, called "d8", into its ASCII value so then I have 8 integers. I then want to add them together to form one integer and display this value into OffFac.Text. But it always displays this error  "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow".

```
Dim d8 As String
Dim Step2 As Integer
d8 = DEight.Text
Dim RandomNumber2C As Char = d8.Substring(0, 1)
Dim RandomNumber22C As Char = d8.Substring(1, 1)
Dim RandomNumber32C As Char = d8.Substring(2, 1)
Dim RandomNumber42C As Char = d8.Substring(3, 1)
Dim RandomNumber52C As Char = d8.Substring(4, 1)
Dim RandomNumber62C As Char = d8.Substring(5, 1)
Dim RandomNumber72C As Char = d8.Substring(6, 1)
Dim RandomNumber82C As Char = d8.Substring(7, 1)
Dim RandomNumberX As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber2C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber2X As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber22C,1))
Dim RandomNumber3X As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber32C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber4X As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber42C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber5X As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber52C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber6X As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber62C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber7X As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber72C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber8X As String = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber82C, 1))
Dim RandomNumberXX As String = CLng(RandomNumberX)
Dim RandomNumber2XX As String = CLng(RandomNumber2X)
Dim RandomNumber3XX As String = CLng(RandomNumber3X)
Dim RandomNumber4XX As String = CLng(RandomNumber4X)
Dim RandomNumber5XX As String = CLng(RandomNumber5X)
Dim RandomNumber6XX As String = CLng(RandomNumber6X)
Dim RandomNumber7XX As String = CLng(RandomNumber7X)
Dim RandomNumber8XX As String = CLng(RandomNumber8X)

Step2 = RandomNumberXX + RandomNumber2XX + RandomNumber3XX + RandomNumber4XX + RandomNumber5XX + RandomNumber6XX + RandomNumber7XX + RandomNumber8XX
Step2 = OffFac.Text
```

Comment: You should study your error but…Taking a higher level view of the requirements, this looks like a checksum of ASCII code units (which happen to be bytes). So, `Dim byte2Long = Function (b As Byte) CLng(b): Dim longSum = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(d8).Select(byte2Long).Sum()` In coding, clarity is king, less is more, and traceability to the problem statement is golden.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate (append a series of strings to one another) a series of numbers that are the ascii values of the numeric characters entered into your text box.

With the string "12345678" you get the following.

"49" + "50" + "51" + "52" + "53" + "54" + "55" + "56" = "4950515253545556"

The number 4950515253545556 is too large to be assigned to an integer.

Also, your last assignment statement should be

```
OffFac.text = step2
```

You probably want to do something like this

```
Dim RandomNumberX As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber2C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber2X As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber22C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber3X As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber32C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber4X As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber42C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber5X As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber52C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber6X As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber62C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber7X As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber72C, 1))
Dim RandomNumber8X As Integer = Asc(Mid(RandomNumber82C, 1))
Dim RandomNumberXX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumberX)
Dim RandomNumber2XX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumber2X)
Dim RandomNumber3XX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumber3X)
Dim RandomNumber4XX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumber4X)
Dim RandomNumber5XX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumber5X)
Dim RandomNumber6XX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumber6X)
Dim RandomNumber7XX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumber7X)
Dim RandomNumber8XX As Integer = CLng(RandomNumber8X)
```